# How to fill gaps in imageview (not covered by image) with color?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I want to create an image of fixed size e.g. 612 by 612. I am using an image picker to select photos from my iphone. So in order to ensure that all the photos fit to the 612 by 612 size without distortion, I am using the following method to re-scale the photo so that they conform to the size of 612 by 612. However as a result, blank spaces might be created in the final image. (see example below)

I am using the following code to scale my image (of fixed size 612 by 612)

```
//Scale the image to fit to imageview
UIImage *image = [self scaleImage:img toRectSize:CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 612)];


//Method to scale image
- (UIImage *)scaleImage:(UIImage *)img toRectSize:(CGRect)screenRect
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size);
    float hfactor = img.size.width / screenRect.size.width;
    float vfactor = img.size.height / screenRect.size.height;

    float factor = MAX(hfactor, vfactor);

    float newWidth = img.size.width / factor;
    float newHeight = img.size.height / factor;

    float leftOffset = (screenRect.size.width - newWidth) / 2;
    float topOffset = (screenRect.size.height - newHeight) / 2;

    CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(leftOffset, topOffset, newWidth, newHeight);
    [img drawInRect:newRect blendMode:kCGBlendModePlusDarker alpha:1];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;   
}
```

As mentioned, as the image is sometimes not a full square, I get a result like what you see below:

[image]

How can I feel up the white spaces in the image with black color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to set the `backgroundColor` of *UIImageView* to `blackColor`.

Another way is to fill the rect with *blackColor* while you scale the image.

```
- (UIImage *)scaleImage:(UIImage *)img toRectSize:(CGRect)screenRect {

    ...
    CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(leftOffset, topOffset, newWidth, newHeight);

    // Fill the original rect with black color
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, screenRect);

    [img drawInRect:newRect blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1];
    ...
}
```

Note that the `blendMode` in *drawInRect:blendMode:alpha:* method is set to `kCGBlendModeNormal`. If you set some other blend modes you will get undesired results. For example, if you set the blend mode to *kCGBlendModePlusDarker* and fill the rect with *blackColor* then the entire image will become black.

Comment: Thanks! Does that mean I have to remove this line [img drawInRect:newRect blendMode:kCGBlendModePlusDarker alpha:1]; and replace it with the 'ModeNormal' one? BTW this works great! Thanks alot!

Comment: Yes. If you want the actual image to be undisturbed you have to use *kCGBlendModeNormal*.

Answer (score 1):

Set the background color on your `UIImageView` to black and you'll get what you want